# Fiber connection only 100 MBit/s instead of 1 GBit/s

Tags: router, fiber

I am facing a rather strange issue that is hard to debug.
I upgraded my internet subscription from 100 MBit/s to 1 GBit/s. Still, the download speed is 100 MBit/s.

I am using a FritzBox 5490 Fiber modem. The FritzBox is connected via a 1 GBit/s ethernet cable to my PC. The problem seems to be the connection between the FritzBox and the Fibre exchange.
And if I open the UI of the router, I get this:
[image: FritzBox Settings]

So, it seems the issue is the fiber optics. The FritzBox is capable of 1 Gbit/s itself, even though it is quite old. My issue is that I don't know how to debug the issue.
I tried multiple fiber optics cables - with the same result. According to the landlord and public services - 1 Gbit/s is available (not sure if they mean to the street or also inside the building).

What could cause that picture and how can I approach the root cause?

Comment: I assume you have contacted your service provider?

Comment: Contacted yes - but I am still waiting for an answer. Assuming the right settings are done on their site, what options do I have to narrow it down?

Comment: You don’t have a lot of options until you eliminate their end as the problem. Fiber must be transported at the same frequency at both ends.

Comment: Does the fiber go directly to the street, or to the landlord's hardware?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know - I'd argue directly to the street, but I don't have definitive proof.

Comment: According to the ISP - 1 GBit down/up is used.
That still leaves room for the router not supporting 1 Gbit/s, which it seems.

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up "Gbit" with "GByte" ?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, it seems it is the router.